# How to find all shortest paths efficiently based on the cost in neo4j using cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

How to find all shortest paths efficiently based on the cost in neo4j (3.1.0) using cypher?

My current approach is to use `allShortestPaths` and then order by

**Sample Data**

```
//node with cost
MERGE (a:A{name:"A"})
MERGE (b:A{name:"B"})
MERGE (c:A{name:"C"})
MERGE (d:A{name:"D"})
MERGE (ee:A{name:"E"})
MERGE (a) -[:R{cost:-4}]-> (b)
MERGE (a) -[:R{cost:-1}]-> (c)
MERGE (a) -[:R{cost:2}]-> (d)
MERGE (b) -[:R{cost:5}]-> (ee)
MERGE (d) -[:R{cost:-2}]-> (ee)
```

**Cypher**

```
//list all paths with cost
MATCH (n1),(n2) ,p=allShortestPaths((n1)-[*..10]->(n2))
WITH 
p,
reduce(cost=0,x in relationships(p) | cost+x.cost) AS cost ,
reduce(s="(",x in nodes(p) | s+"->"+x.name)+")" AS path
ORDER BY cost DESC, LENGTH(p) DESC
return path,cost
```

**Result**

```
╒═════════════╤══════╕
│"path"       │"cost"│
╞═════════════╪══════╡
│"(->B->E)"   │"5"   │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->A->D)"   │"2"   │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->A->B->E)"│"1"   │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->A->D->E)"│"0"   │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->A->C)"   │"-1"  │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->D->E)"   │"-2"  │
├─────────────┼──────┤
│"(->A->B)"   │"-4"  │
└─────────────┴──────┘
```

See
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=lh5lym

Execution Plan

```
Total database accesses: 98
```

is this the correct way to find the shortest path based on cost or if  there is any better/efficient approach (when number of nodes and depth of path increases) ?

Comment: At first glance - everything is OK.